# Are __next__ and __str__ invoked by the equivalent next and str functions internally?

Tags: python, python-internals

From Learning python book 5th Edition:

> Page 421, footnote2:
>
> Technically speaking, the `for` loop calls the internal equivalent of `I.__next__`, instead of the `next(I)` used here, though there is rarely any difference between the two. Your manual iterations can generally use either call scheme.

What does this exactly mean? Does it mean that that `I.__next__` is invoked by a C function instead of `str` builtin function in the `for`loop or any builtin iteration contexts?

> Page 914:
>
> `__str__` is tried first for the `print` operation and the `str` built-in function (the internal equivalent of which `print` runs). It generally should return a user-friendly display.

Aside from book, Does Python calls `__str__` or `__next__` using C functions internally as I understood from the book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python C implementations use C functions that are *essentially* the same thing as the Python functions, in that the Python functions like `str()` and `next()` are usually thin wrappers around the C functions.

These C functions then take care of calling the right hook; this could be the C version of the hook (a slot in a structure pointing to a function), or the Python function on a class.

Now, both `str()` and `next()` are a little more than wrappers here, because there is additional functionality defined by these functions that require a little more implementation work; `next()` takes a 2nd argument that defines a default, for example.

So I'll take `len()` as an example instead. The function is defined in the [`builtin_len()` C function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1323):

```c
static PyObject *
builtin_len(PyObject *self, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t res;

    res = PyObject_Size(v);
    if (res < 0 && PyErr_Occurred())
        return NULL;
    return PyInt_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

Note the call `PyObject_Size()`; that's what C code would use to get the length of an object. The rest is just error handling and producing a Python `int` object.

`PyObject_Size()` then is [implemented like this](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.11/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1323):

```c
Py_ssize_t
PyObject_Size(PyObject *o)
{
    PySequenceMethods *m;

    if (o == NULL) {
        null_error();
        return -1;
    }

    m = o->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
    if (m && m->sq_length)
        return m->sq_length(o);

    return PyMapping_Size(o);
}
```

It takes a `PyObject` structure, finds the `ob_type` structure from there, which has an optional `tp_as_sequence` structure, which can define a `sq_length` function pointer. If it exists, it is called to produce the actual length. Different types can define that function, and a special C structure for *Python* instances can handle redirecting back to a Python method.

All this shows that Python's internal implementation uses a lot of abstractions to implement objects, allowing both C-defined types and Python classes to be treated the same, mostly. If you want to dig deeper, the Python documentation has [full coverage of the C-API](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api), including a [dedicated tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/).

Circling back to your original two functions, the internal equivalent of `next()` is [`PyIter_Next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/iter.html#c.PyIter_Next), and `str()`, as used for string conversions of arbitrary objects, is [`PyObject_Str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_Str).

Comment: That was one great explanation, unfortunately I'm not a C developer, but I like to dig deep in the internals.  Therefore, I conclude from your explanation that `str` and `next` are C functions indeed, and they get to decide to call the right hook which could be either a C or Python function.